# How to apply style on a segmented button in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I would like to create menu like the one in the left figure below. I think that segmented button would be most appropriate for that, but I encountered some problems with applying styles (I also tried radio button, but it is even harder to apply style).

[image]

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.button.Segmented', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            allowMultiple: false,
            vertical: true,
            items: [{
                text: 'Option 1',
                cls: 'btn',
            }, {
                text: 'Option 2',
                cls: 'btn',
                pressed: true
            }, {
                text: 'Option 3',
                cls: 'btn',
            }],
            listeners: {
                toggle: function (container, button, pressed) {
                    alert("User toggled the '" + button.getText() + "' button: " + (pressed ? 'on' : 'off'));
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**app.scss**

```
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    border: none;  
    background: #f2f2f2;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: light;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 24px;
}
.btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: -1;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

When I apply `border-radius` to segmented button it rounds the corners of he whole group of buttons, and not of it's children. How to apply style on children buttons separately?

The other problem associated with using buttons is that I cannot have two text fields like in the figure (Text & Val).

Comment: EXT JS version ?

Comment: @Jone version 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.button.Segmented', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            allowMultiple: false,
            vertical: true,
            items: [{
                text: 'Text3 <span>Val3</span>',
                cls: 'btn',
            }, {
                text: 'Text3 <span>Val3</span>',
                cls: 'btn',
                pressed: true
            }, {
                text: 'Text3 <span>Val3</span>',
                cls: 'btn active',
            }],
            listeners: {
                toggle: function (container, button, pressed) {
                    alert("User toggled the '" + button.getText() + "' button: " + (pressed ? 'on' : 'off'));
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #fff !important;
    font-weight: light;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 13%), 0 -1px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 2%);
}

.btn span {color: #000;}
.btn .x-btn-inner {display: block;  width: 100%;}
.btn .x-btn-inner span {font-weight: bold;float: right;}

.btn.x-btn-menu-active, .btn.x-btn-pressed, .btn.x-btn-over {background: #fff !important; border: 1px solid #2ec9c8 !important;}
```

[image]

Comment: plz check again